# Trying to pass an array of files to a Meteor method

Tags: javascript, meteor

I call a method like so in a submit button event:

```
'submit #form': function(event, tmpl){
    var files = null;
    if(event.target.fileInput)
        files = event.target.fileInput.files;

    console.log(f);

    Meteor.call('insertFiles', files, function(err){
        if(err)
        {
            console.log(err);
        }
        else
        {
            console.log('insertFiles returned.');
            Router.go('next_screen');
        }
    });
}
```

`fileInput`:

```
<input type="file" name="fileInput" id="fileInput"
       accept="image/jpeg, image/png, application/pdf" multiple/>
```

My method:

```
'insertFiles'(files){

    console.log(files);

    //Rest of code.
}
```

In the client console log, I see files like so:

```
FileList {0: File, 1: File, length: 2}
```

But inside the method, the console log outputs this:

```
{ '0': {}, '1': {} }
```

So, I don't see the files inside the method. Why is this? What can I do to get the file list inside the method?

Comment: I think [this tutorial](https://coderwall.com/p/7tpa8w/file-upload-with-meteor-method) may help

Comment: @Kai: I don't think it does. The object itself is gone inside the Meteor method.

Answer (score 4):

You can't just pass variable with either `FileList` or `File` type to the meteor method through DDP.

The most simple method would be to use `FileReader` and read file(s) content as binary string and pass it to the server method, which would save it to the file system or into DB.

**Client side:**

```
'submit #form': function(event, tmpl){
  event.preventDefault();

  const fileInput = document.querySelector('#fileInput');
  const files = _.toArray(fileInput.files);

  let cnt = files.length;
  if (!cnt) {
    return;
  }

  const filesArray = [];
  const addFile = (fileObject) => {
    if (fileObject != null) {
      files.push(fileObject);
    }
    if(!(--cnt)) {
      Meteor.call('insertFiles', filesArray, function(err, res){
        ...
      });
    }
  };

  _.each(files, (file) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    const name = file.name;
    const type = file.type;
    reader.onload = (ev) => {
      addFile({
        name, type,
        content: ev.target.result
      });
    };
    reader.onerror = () => {
      addFile(null);
    };
    reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
  });
}
```

Or, you can use one of the numerous packages designed to help you with uploading/storing files, such as [CollectionFS](https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS), for example.

Comment: I get this error:

`'readAsBinaryString' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'.` at the `reader.readAsBinaryString(file)'` line.